# See summary of multiple commits in SourceTree

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

I have made multiple code commits in my local repository. How do I see the final summary of those code commits combined before pushing the code to remote repository?

Earlier, I used Tortoise GIT(not available in MAC) where I can select those contiguous commits in show log and then `right click->combine to one commit` to see all the summary of my code changes before pushing the code to remote repository.

How do I achieve something similar in SourceTree without involving squash or anything which might change my git commit history

Comment: Is there any other tool in MAC that I can use for achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

If the local commits are continuous commits then you can command+Click the already existing commit and the latest local commit to get the final summary of all those commits between these 2 points.

Answer (score 0):

On windows you can achieve that with both '**CTRL + click**' and '**SHIFT + click**' on the two commits you want to display all changes between.